# Memory usage monitoring in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows

Basically, i'm doing a personal project to monitore the memory usage of an application I choose for the much time as I want, all of that in Windows 10. Not much detail needed.

What i've tried was using the `sys/proctable` module to acess all of my process
Main code:

```rb
process_name = "chrome.exe" #for example
target = processes.find { |process| process.cmdline&.include?(process_name) }
ram_bytes = target.working_set_size
```

But basically the *visible* problem is that .working_set_size return the minimum memory usage to an process to work --- "The Working Set Size (WSS) is how much memory an application needs to keep working"] ---([https://www.brendangregg.com/wss.html#:~:text=The%20Working%20Set%20Size%20(WSS,memory%20that%20is%20frequently%20used.)](https://www.brendangregg.com/wss.html#:%7E:text=The%20Working%20Set%20Size%20(WSS,memory%20that%20is%20frequently%20used.)) -- and that function returns a very small value compared to the memory usage. For example, when the code is runned while chrome is using 400mb of ram, the program might return something about 100-120.

Finally, what I want is a module and a function that can acess the memory usage of some application running in the moment the program is runned. As I've said, my os is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Keep reading the page you linked. Working set size is not what you think it is. You didn't read enough of that page.

I suspect the number you want is the RSS or resident set size.